# ActionScript - Need item to stay 5sec before disappearing

Tags: actionscript, visible

Hello I'm new to AS :( I want to make a pic stay visible for about 5seconds before it disappears. 
Can anyone please help?

The picture is at the start before a loop begins. Thx in advance..I got only this command so far if it's needed or not.... visible = false;

I know there are several ways to do this but I was hoping for your advice. Thanks

Comment: Do other things need to continue while the image is visible, or does everything freeze?

Comment: use [flash.utils.setTimeout()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout()), within the setTimeout callback reference your DisplayObject and set the `visible` property.

Comment: Edit..(rush typing lol) No, this simply needs to stay for a few sec at the start before anything starts then it can disappear. thanks i will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this AS3 right?

I would do addChild() too add it,

then as zamnuts wrote, do a setTimeout for 5 seconds and when the 5 secs are over do a removeChild, and continue with the rest

Comment: Yes AS3. Thanks. Coding is for crazy people. I can't figure out anything. I wish I could just show someone my code and they fix it. Everything is complicating and confusing agghh